# common place to store files on mac and windows

Tags: windows, macos, file, filesystems, file-handling

am writing a java code that needs to save a file.

the below code is for mac.

ImageIO.write(movie_image, "jpg",new File("/Users/sathyap/Desktop/movieimages/"+fileName+".jpg"));

is there a way i can give the directory structure "/Users/sathyap/Desktop/movieimages/"
hardcoded that works for both mac and windows.

Comment: can you store the file somewhere under the current working directory?

Comment: but is it user accessible. i want it to be some were the user can access it easily. like My documents or desktop, etc.

Comment: if a user can launch a program from a directory say "c:\test" ... and if the program can write to that directory ... than the file is also accessible to user ... see my answer below

Comment: But that's not necessarily where you want to store data you want to be readily accessible to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the program runs under a directory (X) in either Mac and Windows. You can code it like this:

```
//This will give the current working directory
String directoryPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

//now get the platform dependent path
String filePath = directoryPath + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "filename";

File fileToWriteTo = new File(filePath);
```

File.separator will take care of platform ... your files will always be saved under current working direcoty ... you can provide shortcuts to access those paths and place them on desktop

If a user can execute the program that writes to that directory ... I will assume that the user can also access the files without problem

Comment: thanks. works great. "If a user can execute the program that writes to that directory ... I will assume that the user can also access the files without problem" thats true.

Comment: This won't work in Windows if your program is installed in Program Files.  It expects you to store post-install files under the user.  user.dir is the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Totally changing my answer because I think what you're looking for is sticking to cross-platform rather than coding for each situation separately.

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```